# yytext matching the end of a regex

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lex

I have a lex file and I'm trying to parse code with it.  For example, I have something like this:

```
...
%%
COMMENT ("(^"|"/^")(.|\n)*("^)"|"^/")
%%
{COMMENT} printf( "comment: %s\n", yytext );
[.]*      printf( "other: %s\n", yytext );
%%
...
```

and in this scenario the input

```
(^^^^^^^^^
this is a comment
^)

function(arg);
sometext
```

is outputting:

```
comment: (^^^^^^^^^
this is a comment
^)

function(arg)
other: ;
sometext
```

etc.  So it matches the ")" but not "^)" and it doesn't match the next seen "^)" but the last one of the file.  I have no options or command line arguments when calling lex. I'm sure this is somehow related to how I'm using literal string matching, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I've had it work using the test site http://regexr.com/39gl2 with the pattern \(\*(.|\n)*?\*\) however, with lex it seems to have no effect.  I don't see how (.|\n)* and (.|\n)*? are different anyway.

Comment: In lex, they are not. I don't know of a regex "test site" which understands lex syntax, but you can come closer by selecting Posix syntax, if available. In lex (and in general) `.*` matches the longest possible sequence, not the sequence up to the "next match".

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read the flex manual, or at least the sections on [patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html) and the following section ["How the input is matched"](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Matching.html). From the latter, I quote:

> If no match is found, then the *default rule* is executed: the next character in the input is considered matched and copied to the standard output.

That's really important. Your matches are actually stopping where you expect them to, but the following text doesn't match any rule, so it is echoed to the output by the default rule. This behaviour is confusing, and -- except in rare cases -- undesirable. So I suggest you turn it off by placing

```
%option nodefault
```

in the first section of your flex input. That will force you to write your own fallback rule, because unmatched characters will throw an error.

Most modern regex libraries allow "non-greedy" repetitions. (Some libraries do not implement this feature very efficiently, however.) But Flex does not. So in Perl, the regex `\(.*?\)` (`*?` is a non-greedy match) will match the first open parenthesis and the characters up to the next close parenthesis, whereas `\(.*\)` will match the first open parenthesis up to the *last* close parenthesis. In Flex, both patterns will match up to the last parenthesis.

Note that `\([^()]*\)` is a much more useful regex: it will match the first *innermost* parenthesized expression: i.e., an open and close parenthesis with no intervening parentheses. Because we explicitly state what we're prepared to match in the middle, there is no difference between greedy and non-greedy matching; the pattern is precise. When possible, that is almost always a better solution. However, it is tricky to apply in the case where the inverted match is more than one character long.

While it is always possible to craft a regular expression which is the inverse of another regular expression, it is not always easy. And a plausible alternative is the use of flex ["start conditions"](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html). In that section, you'll find an example for lexing [C comments](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html#index-comments_002c-example-of-scanning-C-comments) which is somewhat similar to what you are trying to do.